# How to mv all files under a folder exclude some specify files

Tags: bash, macos

I'm using MACOS and want to use mv command to move all *.csv file from folder **/Users/abc/Downloads/** to **/Users/abc/idea-workspace/tofolder/csvfiles**. 
But I need to exclude any file name contains "(" such as "filename(1).csv". These files are duplicate download files. So I don't like to move them into /tofolder/csvfiles.
My question is how to exclude these file contains "(". 
thanks

I try to use "!()" to exclude these files but not work.Even I have used command before.

```sh
shopt -s extglob
```

```sh
mv -f /Users/abc/Downloads/*.csv /Users/abc/idea-workspace/tofolder/csvfiles
```

Comment: Can you show us the *exact* extglob you tried that didn't work?

Comment: *With* any error messages.

Comment: Perhaps try utilizing the following [`find`](https://ss64.com/osx/find.html) command instead: `find /Users/abc/Downloads -depth 1 -type f -name '*.csv' -not -name '*(*).csv' -exec mv {}  /Users/abc/idea-workspace/tofolder/csvfiles \;`

Comment: @RobC, as an extension, I'd make that `-exec mv -t /Users/abc/idea-workspace/tofolder/csvfiles -- {} +` on a system with GNU `mv`; that way you're passing one instance of `mv` as many names as possible, as opposed to starting one `mv` per file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demonstrating an extglob that **does** work:

```
mkdir -p "/tmp/$$" && cd "/tmp/$$"
touch {foo,bar}{'(1)',}.csv
shopt -s extglob
printf '%q\n' !(*[()]*).csv
```

...properly emits:

```
bar.csv
foo.csv
```

Because you didn't show the extglob that didn't work, we can't speak to why.

Comment: Charles, perhaps you need to be more explicit in your answer as to what the `mv` command should be, i.e. `mv -f /Users/abc/Downloads/!(*[()]*).csv /Users/abc/idea-workspace/tofolder/csvfiles` - although the OP itself does raise further questions, as per my comments below it.

Comment: @RobC Thanks you so much. I work while I'm using your command. It is what I want. Thanks all guys help me in it.